# Joomla! 3: Custom plugin event onUserBeforeSave validation

Tags: validation, events, plugins, joomla3.0

i have created custom plugin for validating user profile changing. I having strange issue with event onUserBeforeSave.

To make example as simple as it can be i shorten the code

```
public function onUserBeforeSave($user, $isnew, $new)
{
  JError::raiseWarning(1000, 'Save disabled');      
  return false;
}
```

So i'm returning false on any user data change. Everything works well, joomla throws error and return to profile edit, but data are saved in database.

Is there any possibility to make this work or someone had a different experience?

In advance, thank you!

**EDIT : Ok, im changing my opinion it's saved in user session or cache, because when i return back to profile after failed save i've see that i have changed data, but after relogin (logout, login) data are not changed. How to get rid of that, it may confuse users.**

Answer (score 0):

Destroying the session:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->destroy();
```

By the way, Jerror is deprecated since 11.1. You should use Exception instead:

```
throw new Exception('Save disabled', 1000);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this actually force user to logout. I think that i need to do some kind of refresh user sesstion.

Comment: You can use other JSession methods instead of destroy. If you know the parameter to clear, you can use $session->clear($param_name); method